# Jenkins cli public key authentication: Where to put my public key in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to setup Jenkins using jenkins-cli. From the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI), I know I am supposed to add my public key in Jenkins:

> Login from the web UI and go to http://yourserver.com/me/configure, then set your public keys in the designated text area.

However, when I can't find where to put my public key there, as all I see is the following (see end of message).

Where should the public key be added? and, is it possible to add the public key at a specific path under the $JENKINS_HOME directory (to add the key as part of a shell script)?

[image: jenkins]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in `/configure`, *not* in `/me/configure`: the latter is a shortcut for `/user/yourname/configure`. These keys are obviously user-specific.

Click your user name in Jenkins (top right, needs security enabled), *then* select *Configure* on the left.